# Notify user of message distribution in Sympa

Tags: sympa

I was wondering if it's possible to notify users who have had messages distributed in the same way that if a user gets rejected they get a notification.

There doesn't appear to be any way to turn the feature on.

Answer (score 0):

The distribution notification message is customisable in the `mail_tt2/message_report.tt2` file, as the `message_distributed` entry.

This should be sent on confirmation UNLESS the action in the scenario had a `,quiet` suffix, or the confirmation command specified 'quiet'.

Comment: I believe this will only send notification to the person that distributes the message, but not the person that originally sent the message, which is the problem.  As the moderator, I get the distribution message, but the user who sent the message gets no such message.